# Gradient background repeats despite having "no-repeat" when I scroll

Tags: css, background, gradient, linear-gradients, background-repeat

I've tried searching on here for answers but none of the suggested ones to other's questions have been working for me.

My code for the background is:

```
body {
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom left, #ffe03d, #ff00e6);
background-repeat: no-repeat scroll;
background-size: cover;
color: #f4f4f4;
text-align: center;
}
```

I've also set my HTML's height to 100%. I even tried width, but that did nothing as well.

When I run this, it appears as this in my browser:
[Here it is repeating once I've scrolled down.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GKOE.png)

Is there anything that worked for any of you guys?

Answer (score 3):

I asked my teacher for help during my class and they pointed me towards setting the background-attachment to fixed and that worked! Now the background stretches across the page and doesn't repeat.

```
body {
background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Thank you to everyone for answering!

Comment: This was bugging me for a while. I wanted to confirm for anyone else looking, this solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mentioned below code

```
body {
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom left, #ffe03d, #ff00e6);
background-size:100% 100vh;
color: #f4f4f4;
text-align: center;
}
```

So it is working as you need

Comment: Thank you! Sadly, this didn't change anything. I think that's on me, though, as I wasn't clear in my question what exactly I wanted my background to do. I asked my teacher for help and the told me to set the background-attachment to fixed!
I appreciate your help. Thank you again!! :D

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `height` of `100%` for both html and body tags. And you're good to go.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```